# Calculate the following limit : $\lim_{\alpha\to 0;\alpha >0 } \int_{\alpha}^1 \frac{1}{x(x^n+a)}dx $ , a>0, $n\in N^*$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

$\lim_{\alpha\to 0;\alpha >0} \int_{\alpha}^1 \frac{1}{x(x^n+a)}dx $ , a>0, $n\in N^*$ 
Please help
[image: Here's what I've tryed so far, as you can see I didn't quite finish the limit but worked on the integral]

Comment: What is the set $N^*$ here?

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$ 0<x^n+a\le 1+a, x\in[\alpha,1]$$
and hence one has
$$ \int_\alpha^1\frac1{x(x^n+a)}dx\ge\frac1{1+a}\int_\alpha^1\frac1xdx=\frac1{1+a}(-\ln\alpha). $$
Since $\lim_{\alpha\to0^+}(-\ln \alpha)=\infty$, one has
$$ \lim_{\alpha\to0^+}\int_\alpha^1\frac1{x(x^n+a)}dx=\infty. $$